# How to show the GoogleMaps map and its features in a Fragment class?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps, android-fragments

I have a Mainactivity with a BottomNavigationMenu where I can switch between fragments. In one of these fragments I have a homepage fragment where I should visualize the map with a simple marker.

My question is why the google map doesn't update the camera to the specified fixed position?
Should I implement another class that extends SupportMapFragment to visualize the map properly?

Here is my code:
**Homepage.kt**

```
class HomepageFragment : Fragment(), GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener,
    GoogleMap.OnMyLocationClickListener, OnMapReadyCallback {

    private lateinit var map: GoogleMap
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val mapFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment) as SupportMapFragment?
       mapFragment?.getMapAsync(this)
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_homepage, container, false)
    }

    override fun onMyLocationButtonClick(): Boolean {
        // TODO something
        return false
    }

    override fun onMyLocationClick(location: Location) {
        // TODO something
    }

    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        map = googleMap
        map.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(this)
        map.setOnMyLocationClickListener(this)

        val fixedPosition: LatLng = LatLng(40.1234, 13.1234)
        map.addMarker(
            MarkerOptions()
                .position(fixedPosition)
                .title("My fixed position")
        )
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(fixedPosition))
    }

}
```

**fragment_homepage.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.HomepageFragment">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/map_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Result**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beWP0.jpg)

**What I would expect**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ya5WW.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The error was in these rows:

```
 val mapFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment) as SupportMapFragment?
 mapFragment?.getMapAsync(this)
 return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_homepage, container, false)
```

You have to change in these:

```
val view : View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_homepage, container, false)
val mapFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment) as SupportMapFragment?
mapFragment?.getMapAsync(this)
return view
```

Comment: This is too general a question. You can just as well ask ChatGPT for this. Please come back when you have an actual problem.